# How do I write an Ansible copy function to copy multiple files to the directories of multiple JVMs?

Tags: for-loop, ansible, copy

I have a file on each RHEL server called `JVMNAMES` in the */etc/rc.d/init.d/* directory.
It contains a list of the JVMs on the server with a new JVM name on each line like below.

```
abc-def01
bcd-efg02
cde-fgh01
```

I want to loop through and copy four `.sh` files to the *bin* directory of each JVM.

I have done this with a shell script in the past like this

```bash
LIST=/etc/rc.d/init.d/JVMNAMES

for i in `cat $LIST`
do      
  echo "Updating the needed .sh files for JVM: '$i'..."
  cp /usr/apache/tomcat/tomcat-current/bin/catalina.sh /usr/apache/tomcat/$i/bin/
  cp /usr/apache/tomcat/tomcat-current/bin/version.sh /usr/apache/tomcat/$i/bin/
  cp /usr/apache/tomcat/tomcat-current/bin/startup.sh /usr/apache/tomcat/$i/bin/
  cp /usr/apache/tomcat/tomcat-current/bin/shutdown.sh /usr/apache/tomcat/$i/bin/
done
```

So far, this is the best I have been able to come up with.  I have spent many hours googling this and I have yet to find an example so I thought I would post it.
Is there a better way to do this?  I have not run it as of yet and wanted to get some feedback from someone with experience doing this as we don't currently have a good playground at work.

```yaml
- name: Copy the needed .sh files to the bin directory of each JVM
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    src: "/usr/apache/tomcat/tomcat-current/bin/{{ item }}"
    dest: "/usr/apache/tomcat/{{ jvm_idx }}/bin/"
    owner: mwuser
    group: mwadmin
    mode: "u+rwx,g+rx,o=rx"
  with-items:
  - catalina.sh
  - version.sh
  - startup.sh
  - shutdown.sh
  loop: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/rc.d/init.d/JVMNAMES') }}"
  loop_control:
    index_var: jvm_idx
```

Comment: You cannot have both a `loop` and `with_items` in a task, so that won't indeed do.

Comment: Also important to know for you: _lookups_ are executed on the controller. [_Like all templating, lookups execute and are evaluated on the Ansible control machine._](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#lookup-plugins), so your lookup won't do what you want either.

Comment: So do I need to have four different copy entries then?  One for each .sh file.  How do I loop through the JVMs listed in the file stored on the RHEL server?

Comment: No, there are filters to achieve those kind of behaviours.

Comment: I changed the question back to the original so that the answers made more sense.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there are indeed a few issues in your current task:

1. You cannot have two loops in a task at the same time. So, the keywords `with_items` and `loop` cannot coexist in the same task. But you can use the [`product`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/product_filter.html) filter to create a cartesian product of the list of JVM and scripts to copy.
2. Lookups are executed on the Ansible controller, so you will need something else to achieve the task of getting the content of that remote file, like a [`slurp`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/slurp_module.html) task.

   > Like all templating, lookups execute and are evaluated on the Ansible control machine.

   <sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#lookup-plugins*</sup>
3. The default behaviour of the `copy` module is to copy from the controller to a remote node. Here, you want to copy form the remote to the remote, so you'll need to use the [`remote_src`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#parameter-remote_src) parameter.

All this together:

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.slurp:
    src: /etc/rc.d/init.d/JVMNAMES
  register: jvm_names

- ansible.builtin.copy::
    src: "/usr/apache/tomcat/tomcat-current/bin/{{ item.1 }}"
    dest: "/usr/apache/tomcat/{{ item.0 }}/bin/{{ item.1 }}"
    remote_src: true
    owner: mwuser
    group: mwadmin
    mode: u+rwx,g+rx,o=rx
  loop: "{{ jvm_names.content | b64decode | split | product(_scripts) }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.1 }} for JVM {{ item.0 }}"
  vars:
    _scripts:
      - catalina.sh
      - version.sh
      - startup.sh
      - shutdown.sh
```

---

Example with a `debug` task instead of a `copy` one, the two tasks:

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.slurp:
    src: /etc/rc.d/init.d/JVMNAMES
  register: jvm_names

- ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg:
      src: "/usr/apache/tomcat/tomcat-current/bin/{{ item.1 }}"
      dest: "/usr/apache/tomcat/{{ item.0 }}/bin/{{ item.1 }}"
      remote_src: true
      owner: mwuser
      group: mwadmin
      mode: u+rwx,g+rx,o=rx
  loop: "{{ jvm_names.content | b64decode | split | product(_scripts) }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.1 }} for JVM {{ item.0 }}"
  vars:
    _scripts:
      - catalina.sh
      - version.sh
      - startup.sh
      - shutdown.sh
```

would yield the dictionaries:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=catalina.sh for JVM abc-def01) => 
  msg:
    dest: /usr/apache/tomcat/abc-def01/bin/catalina.sh
    group: mwadmin
    mode: u+rwx,g+rx,o=rx
    owner: mwuser
    remote_src: true
    src: /usr/apache/tomcat/tomcat-current/bin/catalina.sh
ok: [localhost] => (item=version.sh for JVM abc-def01) => 
  msg:
    dest: /usr/apache/tomcat/abc-def01/bin/version.sh
    group: mwadmin
    mode: u+rwx,g+rx,o=rx
    owner: mwuser
    remote_src: true
    src: /usr/apache/tomcat/tomcat-current/bin/version.sh
ok: [localhost] => (item=startup.sh for JVM abc-def01) => 
  msg:
    dest: /usr/apache/tomcat/abc-def01/bin/startup.sh
    group: mwadmin
    mode: u+rwx,g+rx,o=rx
    owner: mwuser
    remote_src: true
    src: /usr/apache/tomcat/tomcat-current/bin/startup.sh
ok: [localhost] => (item=shutdown.sh for JVM abc-def01) => 
  msg:
    dest: /usr/apache/tomcat/abc-def01/bin/shutdown.sh
    group: mwadmin
    mode: u+rwx,g+rx,o=rx
    owner: mwuser
    remote_src: true
    src: /usr/apache/tomcat/tomcat-current/bin/shutdown.sh
ok: [localhost] => (item=catalina.sh for JVM bcd-efg02) => 
  msg:
    dest: /usr/apache/tomcat/bcd-efg02/bin/catalina.sh
    group: mwadmin
    mode: u+rwx,g+rx,o=rx
    owner: mwuser
    remote_src: true
    src: /usr/apache/tomcat/tomcat-current/bin/catalina.sh
ok: [localhost] => (item=version.sh for JVM bcd-efg02) => 
  msg:
    dest: /usr/apache/tomcat/bcd-efg02/bin/version.sh
    group: mwadmin
    mode: u+rwx,g+rx,o=rx
    owner: mwuser
    remote_src: true
    src: /usr/apache/tomcat/tomcat-current/bin/version.sh
ok: [localhost] => (item=startup.sh for JVM bcd-efg02) => 
  msg:
    dest: /usr/apache/tomcat/bcd-efg02/bin/startup.sh
    group: mwadmin
    mode: u+rwx,g+rx,o=rx
    owner: mwuser
    remote_src: true
    src: /usr/apache/tomcat/tomcat-current/bin/startup.sh
ok: [localhost] => (item=shutdown.sh for JVM bcd-efg02) => 
  msg:
    dest: /usr/apache/tomcat/bcd-efg02/bin/shutdown.sh
    group: mwadmin
    mode: u+rwx,g+rx,o=rx
    owner: mwuser
    remote_src: true
    src: /usr/apache/tomcat/tomcat-current/bin/shutdown.sh
ok: [localhost] => (item=catalina.sh for JVM cde-fgh01) => 
  msg:
    dest: /usr/apache/tomcat/cde-fgh01/bin/catalina.sh
    group: mwadmin
    mode: u+rwx,g+rx,o=rx
    owner: mwuser
    remote_src: true
    src: /usr/apache/tomcat/tomcat-current/bin/catalina.sh
ok: [localhost] => (item=version.sh for JVM cde-fgh01) => 
  msg:
    dest: /usr/apache/tomcat/cde-fgh01/bin/version.sh
    group: mwadmin
    mode: u+rwx,g+rx,o=rx
    owner: mwuser
    remote_src: true
    src: /usr/apache/tomcat/tomcat-current/bin/version.sh
ok: [localhost] => (item=startup.sh for JVM cde-fgh01) => 
  msg:
    dest: /usr/apache/tomcat/cde-fgh01/bin/startup.sh
    group: mwadmin
    mode: u+rwx,g+rx,o=rx
    owner: mwuser
    remote_src: true
    src: /usr/apache/tomcat/tomcat-current/bin/startup.sh
ok: [localhost] => (item=shutdown.sh for JVM cde-fgh01) => 
  msg:
    dest: /usr/apache/tomcat/cde-fgh01/bin/shutdown.sh
    group: mwadmin
    mode: u+rwx,g+rx,o=rx
    owner: mwuser
    remote_src: true
    src: /usr/apache/tomcat/tomcat-current/bin/shutdown.sh
```